# HTML lists with and without extra space between items

Tags: html, css, list

I have 25 chapters in an HTML book, each with a live Table of Contents. To display the TOCs concisely (the longest has 75 items), I use an uncounted list in a 3-column newspaper format.  In the body of the chapter I want  extra space between list items, obtained with an   (li   margin-top:8px;)  in the CSS file.  But to keep the TOC compact, I want no extra space there.

I had hoped that a selector like
div li (margin:0;) or
tcnt li (margin-top:0px)
would undo the extra space in the TOC, but no such luck.  After trying many variants of selectors, I haven’t found one that removes the added margin from the TOC, despite the TOC list being wrapped in div, nav, ul, an id, and the newspaper class.   The margin-top over-rules everything I have tried.  Is there a way to do this?

(br)(br) inside every  li  that needs extra space will work, but it's clumsy.

The code below produced both kinds of lists.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  li       { margin-top: 8px; } 
  .newsp {
    padding-left: 1mm ;
    column-gap  : 2mm ;
    column-count: 3   ;
    column-width: 33% ;
    column-rule : 1px dashed black;
    line-height : 1.0 ; /* fails */
    font-size   : 10pt;
    font-family : Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border      : black solid 1px ;
      list-style-type: none;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

/* Sample TOC, no extra space wanted */
<div>
  <nav>
    <ul id="tcnt" class="newsp">
      <li>Scarfuem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>ipsum</li>
      <li>gribnac</li>
      <li>rimenko</li>
      <li>plebem</li>
      <li>mansci</li>
      <li>opolibus</li>
      <li>bisquor</li>
    </ul>
  <nav>
</div>

/* Ordinary list, extra vertical space */
<ul>
  <li>Chimban ...</li>
  <li>Grotfen ...</li>
  <li>Milcotus ...</li>
  <li>Pusbah ...</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give your ordinary list its own class (like `ordinary-list` for example) you can target the list items inside it specifically, like so:

```
ul.ordinary-list li
```

```css
ul {
  padding:0px;
}

li {
  
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.ordinary-list li {
 margin-top: 8px;
 }

.newsp {
  padding-left: 1mm;
  column-gap: 2mm;
  column-count: 3;
  column-width: auto;
  column-rule: 1px dashed black;
  line-height: 1.0;
   border: black solid 1px;
   margin-top: 8px;
  /* fails */
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  /* Sample TOC, no extra space wanted */
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul id="tcnt" class="newsp">
        <li>Scarfuem</li>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>ipsum</li>
        <li>gribnac</li>
        <li>rimenko</li>
        <li>plebem</li>
        <li>mansci</li>
        <li>opolibus</li>
        <li>bisquor</li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
  </div>

  /* Ordinary list, extra vertical space */
  <ul class="ordinary-list">
    <li>Chimban ...</li>
    <li>Grotfen ...</li>
    <li>Milcotus ...</li>
    <li>Pusbah ...</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here is the simple working code developed from the response I got yesterday.  Thank you!  (The colors are for development only; the 4mm spacing to overemphasize the result.)
     
     li  { /* In text */
     color:red;
     margin-top: 4mm ;
    }

    li:last-of-type  {
     margin-bottom: 4mm;
    }

    nav li {  /* In TOC */
     color: blue;
     margin-top   : 0 ;
     margin-bottom: 0 ;
    }

Comment: @Tloyoc If this is the most suitable answer, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1027611) the answer by clicking the check mark

Comment: This is most suitable answer.  But I can't find the check mark to click,  (Saw it on a sample page, but not around here.  ?)